# Why won't this MongoDB query work?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a reason I'm unaware of that would cause this query to fail?

Specifically it's the `features: {$in: featuresArray}` part that causes the query to fail.

```
Collection.find({
  features: {
    $in: featuresArray
  },
  location: {
    $near : {
      $geometry : {
        type : 'Point',
        coordinates: [long, lat]
      }
    }
  }},
 {
   sort: {
     score: -1
   }
});`
```

Comment: How did you define featureArray?

Comment: The sort spec is wrong here. But what is the error you are getting that makes you think the addition of searching on the features field is causing the problem? Could do with more information in your post.

Comment: This is using a JS framework, not in the shell, so yeah, the `sort()` is different.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a silly mistake I made in my code.  It had to do with nesting, so this was more an oversight/typo error.

Answer (score 2):

As the docs for [`db.collection.find`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) says, the second argument for the find should be for projection - ie. which all fields to return in the result. But here you are using the second paramater to sort the results.

I think it should be done like :

```
Collection.find({
    features: {
        $in: featuresArray
    },
    location: {
        $near : {
            $geometry : {
                type : 'Point',
                coordinates: [long, lat]
            }
        }
    }
}).sort({
    score: -1
});
```

Comment: Can you delete your answer?  I realized my silly mistake and fixed my code.  Had added a field and so thus needed to do 'features.name': featuresArray now.

Comment: This is using a JS framework, not in the shell, so yeah, the sort() is different